# list of booleans to slice DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I'm trying to find a less manual, more convenient way to slice a Pandas DataFrame based on multiple boolean conditions. To illustrate what I'm after, here is a simplified example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[True,False,True,False,False,True],'col2':[False,False,True,True,False,False]})
```

suppose I am interested in the subset of the DataFrame where both 'col1' and 'col2' are **True**. I can find this by running:

```
df[(df['col1']==True) & (df['col2']==True)]
```

This is manageable enough in a small dimensional example like this one, but the real one can have up to a hundred columns, so rather than have to string together a long boolean like the one above, I would rather read the columns of interest into a list, e.g.

```
['col1','col2']
```

and select where those columns listed are **True**

Comment: `df.loc[df[magic_list_of_columns].all(axis='columns')]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need all columns:

```
df[df.all(axis=1)==True]
```

If you have list of columns:

```
df[df[COLS].all(axis=1)==True]
```

For opposite just do `False`:

```
df[df.all(axis=1)==False]
```

Comment: i think the opposite case is not what I'm after . from my original example, I would be looking for index 1 and 4

Comment: to elaborate, in one instance a) I want to slice for the rows where the values for the list of columns is "True" and in the other instance b) where they are "False"

Comment: i think this would be: df[df[COLS].any(axis=1)==False]

Comment: The last case should be `df[~df.all(axis=1)]`